# How to use something like Try-Catch inside CUDA device code

Tags: cuda

Is there a way to execute a statement inside the device code without raising CUDA error?
Something looks like the following:

```
__global__ void myKernel(float* X1, float* X2, float* Y){
try{
    Y[0] = X1[0] / X2[0];
   }catch(){
    Y[0] = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

I know that we can check the value of X2[0] before division, but what If I want to execute the statement without checking for valid inputs, and execute it safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently, [CUDA device code does not support exception handling](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#exception-handling).

`try`/`catch` cannot be used in CUDA device code.

If a statement would cause a device side error (e.g. out-of-bounds access, for example), there is no way to execute that statement in device code without triggering the device side error.

To avoid the error, you would need to modify the statement, or conditionally not execute it, to avoid triggering the device side error.